# Google Earth maps within c# Forms app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, google-maps

Is it possible to add Google Maps functionality to a .Net Forms application? There seems to be a few that show how to do it in a Web application... but none that I can find that embed the maps within a fosm app, allowing zooming and clicking functionality.

Comment: do  you necessary want google map, or can you consider using bing maps ?

Comment: Any is OK... I just need to be able to add an overlay.. as in, plot the flight path of an aircraft, and add markers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [GMap.Net](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/) with great success. From the ones I found, I was by far the best one.

You get a control that you can add to a WinForms application that gives you a view that looks and behaves like Google maps does in a web browser. You can also manipulate the map programmatically in C# using an API that resembles the official JavaScript Google Maps API.

Comment: I use it as well - but there is a major licensing issue with it. See the help forums for it. It shares the same DevID.. etc, for all users of it, which is against Google policy - and is why I am wanting to use Google directly. But you're right - GMap is fantastic.

Comment: @cdotlister: In the `GMaps` class, you can set the `GoogleMapsAPIKey` property to your API key. API calls will then be made with your key.

Comment: The major licensing issue is that any use of the google maps static api outside webbrowser is stricly prohibited.(Paragraph 10.8 of the google maps api terms)

Comment: @Fedearne: I'd agree with what you said. GMap.Net does also have the ability to use other maps which do not have licencing problems (eg. OpenStreetMap).

Comment: @Fedearne: The Google Maps API FAQ states that you *can* use the maps in a desktop application: [FAQ](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/maps/faq.html#tos_nonweb).

Comment: @adrianbanks ther terms also states that it has to be in a browser. Another issue witg GMap.NET is, that it does NOT use the static API, but rather issues undocumented request to the google maps server impersonating a Mozilla browser. This violates the terms [FAQ](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/maps/faq.html#tos_tiles)